# loose string search within an array with C#

Tags: c#, search, cpu-word

lets say we have a

```
string[] array = {"telekinesis", "laureate", "Allequalsfive", "Indulgence"};
```

and we need to find a word within this array

normally we'd do following: (or use any similar method to find a string)

```
bool result = array.Contains("laureate"); // returns true
```

In my case, the word that I am searching for, may have errors in it (as the title suggests).

For example, I can't distinguish a difference between letters "I"(large "i") and "l"(small "L") and "1"(number one).

Is there any way how I can find a word such as **"Allequalsfive" or "A11equalsfive" or "AIIequalsfive"**? (loose search) Normally result will be "false".

If only I can specify to ignore some letters.. (the sequence is constant, other letters are constants).

Comment: a good area to look at would be the Levenshtein distance algorithm, often used in spell checkers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of extension methods & [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm

```
var array = new string[]{ "telekinesis", "laureate", 
                          "Allequalsfive", "Indulgence" };

bool b = array.LooseContains("A11equalsfive", 2); //returns true
```

-

```
public static class UsefulExtensions
{
    public static bool LooseContains(this IEnumerable<string> list, string word,int distance)
    {
        foreach (var s in list)
            if (s.LevenshteinDistance(word) <= distance) return true;
        return false;
    }

    //
    //http://www.merriampark.com/ldcsharp.htm
    //
    public static int LevenshteinDistance(this string s, string t)
    {
        int n = s.Length;
        int m = t.Length;
        int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

        // Step 1
        if (n == 0)
            return m;

        if (m == 0)
            return n;

        // Step 2
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++){}

        for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++){}

        // Step 3
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            //Step 4
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {
                // Step 5
                int cost = (char.ToUpperInvariant(t[j - 1]) == char.ToUpperInvariant(s[i - 1])) ? 0 : 1;

                // Step 6
                d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                    Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                    d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
            }
        }
        // Step 7
        return d[n, m];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Contains` overload that takes an [`IEqualityComparer<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx).

Implement your own equality comparer that ignores the letters you want and off you go.

Answer (score 1):

if you only need to know if the word is loosely contained in your array, then you can just "clean" the letters you want to ignore (e.g. replace "1" by "l") in both your search word and array:

```
Func<string, string> clean = x => x.ToLower().Replace('1', 'l');
var array = (new string[] { "telekinesis", "laureate", "A11equalsfive", "Indulgence" }).Select(x => clean(x));          
bool result = array.Contains(clean("allequalsfive"));
```

Otherwise you can look up the Where() LINQ keyword, which lets you filter an array based on a function that you specify.